# How to repeat column until next value is encountered

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to repeat the category column until the next value is encountered. Below is the structure of the table:

```
Category    Term      Date
-------------------- --------------
category1   a         12/7/2012
NULL        b         12/7/2012
NULL        c         12/7/2012
category2   a         13/7/2012
NULL        b         13/7/2012
```

Desired Output:

```
 Category    Term      Date
-------------------- --------------
category1   a         12/7/2012
category1   b         12/7/2012
category1   c         12/7/2012
category2   a         13/7/2012
category2   b         13/7/2012
```

I tried with `Lead` and `Lag` function but it didn't work.

Comment: Which field defines the order? You cannot assume an order by default.

Comment: Thanks! @trincot for formatting it.  There are only these two columns. So Term.

Comment: how the value NULL comes into table

Comment: It's a pre-defined table which has nulls in category columns. I can just select values from it.

Comment: You cannot assume an order if you have no objective way to order them by the column values. One time the engine may choose to produce them in a different order than the previous time, and you will not know which category a record will belong to.

Comment: @trincot I have a date column as well. If it can help.

Comment: Do you always have just a single non-null Category per date?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Yes

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this kind of data structure is bad. If a record belongs to a certain category, it should be mentioned in that record, and not have to be derived from some ordering in a result set.

And speaking of order: you cannot assume an order if you have no objective way to order the records by the column values.

As in an edit to your question you provided an extra column `Date`, it becomes possible to produce the desired result, provided that this date uniquely identifies the category:

You could write this query:

```
select max(category) over (partition by [Date]) as category,
       term
from   mytable;
```

That will yield the desired output:

```
Category    Term
--------------------
category1    a
category1    b
category1    c
category2    a
category2    b
```

Comment: I've never seen an `OVER()` clause used with an aggregate function like `MAX()`, only with window functions, so this is really cool to see.

Answer (score -1):

Assumes that your table has an Id column which is sorted ascending.
If it does not, you can create a new Id number by row_number() function.

```
        DECLARE @temps AS TABLE
        (
            Id int IDENTITY(1,1),
            Category varchar(30),
            Term varchar(10)
        )
        INSERT INTO  @temps VALUES ('category1', 'a')
        INSERT INTO @temps VALUES (NULL, 'b')
        INSERT INTO @temps VALUES (NULL, 'c')
        INSERT INTO @temps VALUES ('category2', 'a')
        INSERT INTO @temps VALUES (NULL, 'b')

        SELECT (
                    SELECT TOP 1 t2.Category 
                    FROM @temps t2 
                    WHERE t2.Id <= t.Id AND t2.Category IS NOT NULL 
                    ORDER BY t2.Id DESC
                ) AS Category,
        t.Term
        FROM @temps t
```